# How to call the function which has another function as parameter in scala?

Tags: scala

Please advise how I can call the below function which has a function as one of the parameters.

```
def totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter(donutType: String)(quantity: 
       Int)(f: Double => Double): Double = {
  println(s"Calculating total cost for $quantity $donutType")
  val totalCost = 2.50 * quantity
  f(totalCost)
}
```

Comment: `totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("Glazed")(4)(d => d*0.5)`

Answer (score 1):

First create a function:

```
val discountByTenPercent: Double => Double =
  priceBeforeDiscount => 0.9 * priceBeforeDiscount
```

Then call the function which as a function as one of the parameters:

```
totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("...")(5)(discountByTenPercent)
```

Of course, you can also create the function in the same line:

```
totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("...")(5)(priceBeforeDiscount => 0.9 * priceBeforeDiscount)
```

If a parameter list only contains one argument that needs to be a function, you can also use braces instead of the parentheses:

```
totalCostWithDiscountFunctionParameter("...")(5) { priceBeforeDiscount =>
  0.9 * priceBeforeDiscount
}
```

By the way, a "function which has another function as parameter" is called a "higher-order function".